# Document browser app in iOS 15 keeps creating iCloud drive folder

Tags: swift, icloud-drive, ios15, uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller

I have had a document browser app up since iOS 11 (using UIKit/UIDocumentBrowserViewController). The app (let's call it "MyApp") used to create a "MyApp" folder in iCloud Drive (and/or on the device, depending on the choice made in Settings), where documents would be saved automatically.

After updating my device to iOS 15 and recompiling, without any changes to the code, *the app seems not to recognize its own folder in iCloud Drive anymore*. Every time a file is opened/imported from outside the app (Files, Mail, etc.), *the app creates a **new** "MyApp" folder in iCloud Drive* and saves the document there. The existing folder is renamed "MyApp 2" (and then "MyApp 3", "MyApp 4" etc. if I try to import another document).

This seems to happen only in iCloud Drive. If I choose in Settings to save documents on my device, all documents are automatically imported into the "My App" folder, as it was the case in iOS 14 and earlier.

I also tried to create a test app from scratch using the Xcode 13 UIKit document-based app template, and the behavior seems to be exactly the same... so it looks like a bug in UIDocumentBrowserViewController was introduced with the iOS update.

Did anyone notice the same? Is there a solution/workaround? Should a bug report be filed?

Thank you for your help.

[EDIT] If anybody is interested, this is the simplest way to reproduce the issue using the Xcode template:

- Create a new project in Xcode 13.0
- Choose iOS -> Document App
- Choose Interface: Storyboard and create the project (for simplicity let’s use “MyApp” as Product Name)
- Build and install MyApp on a device running iOS 15.0 or 15.0.1 with iCloud Drive enabled
- Leave the default setting for Document Storage (i.e. iCloud Drive) in Settings -> MyApp
- Create a text file with any content and save it with extension “exampletext” (i.e. the imported type identifier used by the app template - let’s call the file “test.exampletext”)
- Send an email to an inbox accessible from the device with test.exampletext as attachment
- Open Mail on the device, long-press on test.exampletext and share it to MyApp
- If a folder “MyApp” exists in iCloud Drive, it will be renamed to “MyApp 2”; a new “MyApp” folder will be created and test.exampletext will be saved in the new folder
- Sharing again test.exampletext from the mail to MyApp will create another “MyApp” folder and rename the previous one; an arbitrary number of “MyApp n” folders can be created in this way, each including one copy of the document

Comment: Definitely report this to Apple, please.

Comment: I did, I submitted the above description via the Apple Feedback Assistant yesterday. I hope this can/will be fixed soon...

Comment: Still not fixed in 15.1.  Just ridiculous.  I reached out to developer support and they said file a feedback.  I’m trying with them again.

Comment: @emime They seemed to acknowledge my feedback today.

Comment: @cvb Thank you, let's hope for the best. My feedback was submitted on Oct 4, and in the feedback assistant it still says "Open" with "Less than 10" similar reports: I am a bit surprised, are there so few apps using UIDocumentBrowserViewController out there?

Comment: @emime I think thats the case.  It’s obvious they created the bug doing something else.  It was fine in iOS 14.

Comment: @emime Apple reached out to me.  It's fixed in the 15.2 beta.   A good way to get them to fix things seems to be via developer services.  I guess for really bad bugs though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the 15.2 beta.